# Offering a bounty on a low score question, no new answers

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties, expired-bounty

I recently placed my first bounty on the following question (from someone else):

[How to segment part of moving image based on details from fixed image in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21090541/2777181)

hoping that a 100 rep reward (which, for MATLAB-tagged questions is roughly the equivalent to answering 10 questions) would attract some attention and maybe a good answer. 
But there are no new answers and the bounty period is over.

Is is because the question has been downvoted several times? I consider myself a novice on SO and I'd prefer not to throw my rep out of the window for no answers again.

**Edit:** can I (should I) migrate the question and the bounty to another SE site, such as the Signal Processing one, which is likely to be more suitable?

Comment: There could be any number of reasons, we can only really guess.  Perhaps your question is too hard for most/all readers, perhaps it's not understandable, perhaps it's just not interesting, who knows.

Comment: Remember that a bounty is something that is meant to attract attention. It is absolutely not a guarantee that any new attention will draw out any answers.

Comment: @AlienArrays Disagree, all depends on the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There can be a number of reasons why a bounty does not attract an answer to an existing question.  The question you linked already has what appears to be a pretty good answer on it.  The question also seems fairly domain-specific, so maybe there aren't that many people frequenting Stack Overflow who know how to answer it well.

Sometimes the question itself is the problem.  If it's not a high-quality question in the first place, it might not attract good answers anyway, despite the bounty.

You can help the question along by editing out the flotsam, like the "as a new user, I'm unable to attach more than two links," and the useless signature and "best regards."

Also, if you're expecting someone to hand you a complete, bug-free and documented solution from whole cloth, your expectations may be unrealistic.

Comment: Editing the question is good advice. As for your last sentence, I don't have that level of expectation.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, you **cannot** predict what you will get by offering a bounty. It does not garantee new answers or better answers. It simply puts it in a different section with other featured questions and therefore, making it easier to spot amongs all questions on SO.

Now for the fact that you didn't get any new answers I think the first comment that you have on your post is quite self-explanatory :

> DE, your post is a little bit out of scope; SO is for small response. You have an image processing (segmentation) issue you can find a lot of code at mathworks.com/matlabcentral . Try mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/… for instance. Border the answer to few possibilities, then guys will help you; at the moment the issue is too vague.